# How to change default error message in Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

How to change default error message to custom error message: my custom message

```
const VALIDATION_SCHEME = Yup.object().shape({
      numOne: Yup.Number().required('!'),
      numTwo: Yup.Number()
        .required('!')
        .when('numOne', ((numOne, schema) => schema.max(numOne - 1)))
    });
```

Comment: `.required('my custom message')`

Comment: numTwo: Yup.Number()
        .when('numOne', ((numOne, schema) => schema.max(numOne - 1)))
        .required('my custom message') 
===
don't working
'numTwo must be less than or equal to ${numOne - 1}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternative:

```
numOne: yup.number()
  .required("1")
  .moreThan(yup.ref("numTwo"), "This is 1"),
numTwo: yup.number()
  .required("2")
  .lessThan(yup.ref("numOne"), "This is 2")
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use moreThan hook to perform the validation you want as below.

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  numOne: yup.string().required("Custom 2"),
  numTwo: yup
    .number()
    .lessThan(yup.ref("numOne"), "Your Custom Message")
    .max(yup.ref("numOne"))
});
```

Working example -  https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-cache-k2g4lc?file=/index.js

Comment: don't working, only default message 'numTwo must be less than or equal to ${numOne - 1}'

Comment: I think it should be `lessThan` as op says something like `numTwo must be less than or equal to...` but its not covering `equal to` case. Is it?

Comment: Well, thanks for it. we can use.max to check the equal to clause

Comment: Thanks a lot,
I modified your answer a bit,